# Hadoop 3.1.1 Commands not giving output Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, log4j

When I run `hadoop version` or `hadoop help` or `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version`

I get nothing back.

I have my Log4j.properties file

I downloaded with HomeBrew. I just finished working on my configuration file when I noticed this issue.

Thank you in advice.